# org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException -->Help me fix this

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

```
public String deleteCounterParty(List<CounterParty>counterParties)
{
    String message = "";
    for(CounterParty counterParty:counterParties) {
        if (counterParty.getId() != null && counterPartyRepository.getById(counterParty.getId()) != null) {
            counterPartyRepository.deleteById(counterParty.getId());
            message="deleted successfully";
        }
        else {
            message="id not found";
        }
    }

  return message;

}
```

I'm using this method to delete rows by giving list of ids if the given id is found it is deleted,if not it throws this **EmptyResultDataAccessException** help me fix this

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code for CounterPartyRepository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data access exception thrown when a result was expected to have at least one row (or element) but zero rows (or elements) were actually returned.

Use a try-catch block to catch the exception if thrown and alter your logic accordingly so that when the code follows a happy path, at least one row is returned.

> try { //code to delete rows } catch(final
> EmptyResultDataAccessException e) { //exception message }